# Using || operator in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, logical-operators

I've a small example to use || operator with `Where()` but something may be wrong:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
   "One",
   "Two",
   "Three"
};

string s = "One";
var numbers = list.Where(x => x == s || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

foreach(var number in numbers)
{
   Console.WriteLine(number);

   // output:
   // One
   // Two
   // Three
}

s = null;    
numbers = list.Where(x => x == s || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

foreach(var number in numbers)
{
   Console.WriteLine(number);

   // output:
   // One
   // Two
   // Three
}
```

In the first case, why was `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)` still checked when we had `x == s` true?

I understood:

```
if (A && B)
{
   // we need A and B are true
}

if (A || B)
{
   // we need A is true or B is true
   // if A is true, no ned to check B is true or not
}
```

So, my question is: what did I misunderstand?

Comment: Because it evaluates the query for each element of the list.

Comment: Well, the question is asked per record basis. So `"Two"` => `"Two" == "One" || !string.IsNullOrEmpty("Two")`

Comment: `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)` is always true for each of those strings in your list. Your LINQ is "include when the string is equal to One or when the string is not null and not empty"

Comment: Why would you think that the first list item was checked against the second half of your Where clause? it seems to work as expected: first item passes because it equals `s`, the others pass the second part of the Where check because they're not empty.

Comment: @HappyCoding Why is it that you think `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)` was checked in the first case? "One" is true for `x == s` but for "Two" and "Three" `x != s` therefore it checks the expression after your `||`.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a perfectly valid question, with good example code.  The fact that the OP does not understand how the Where method works does not warrant a downvote.

Comment: @DarrenYoung You think using a method without having any idea what it does, and then asking others why it behaves the way it does, and not so much as looking at the documentation of the method, or any of the tens of thousands of resources online that explain what it does, makes for a good SO question?

Comment: @Servy To a certain level I would say that your statement fits the vast majority of questions posted on SO.

Comment: @DarrenYoung I don't know about the *vast* majority, but yes, there are a *lot* of questions posted to SO where the author clearly didn't do even a basic level of research before asking the question.  Those questions should be downvoted.  We don't want SO to become just lmgtfy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right in saying that:

```
a || b
```

Will not evaluate `b` if `a` is `true`, but:

`Where` LINQ using Lambda expression checks **every** element in the Enumerable regardless of the previous result. Thus when you do:

```
string s = "One";
var numbers = list.Where(x => x == s || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

It checks every element in the query whenever the `Where` lambda expression is valid:

```
x == s || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)); //x = "One", x == s is true
x == s || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)); //x = "Two", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) is true
x == s || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)); //x = "Three", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) is true
```

Thus you got all the elements.

Consider using `TakeWhile` if you want to stop taking the query result as soon as a condition is no longer reached.

Answer (score 4):

`var numbers = list.Where(x => x == s || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));` takes each element from list - `x` and checks if it fits specific condition.

The condition is  `x == s` OR `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)`, so element should fit at least one part of the condition.

Particularly, every element of list meets the `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)` condition.

Try to add `null` to your list. It doesn't meet the `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)` and doesn't meet  `x == s`, so it won't be included in result.

```
 var list = new List<string>
 {
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        null
 };

var numbers = list.Where(x => x == "One" || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator is correct . In your first example:

```
string s = "One";
var numbers = list.Where(x => x == s || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

foreach(var number in numbers)
{
   Console.WriteLine(number);

   // output:
   // One <-- First condition is met
   // Two <-- First condition is not met so goes into the OR operator and returns true
   // Three <--Same as above
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx